# Why define create_foo() in a Django models.Manager instead of overriding create()?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

Reading the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects), it advices to make a custom creation method for a model named `Foo` by defining it as `create_foo` in the manager:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def create_book(self, title):
        book = self.create(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return book

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = BookManager()

book = Book.objects.create_book("Pride and Prejudice")
```

My question is that why is the previous one preferred to simply overriding the base class's `create` method:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, title):
        book = self.model(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        book.save()
        return book

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = BookManager()

book = Book.objects.create("Pride and Prejudice")
```

Imo it seems that only overriding `create` will prevent anyone from accidentally using it to make a illformed model instance, since `create_foo` can always be bypassed completely:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def create_book(self, title):
        book = self.create(title=title, should_not_be_set_manually="critical text")
        return book

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    should_not_be_set_manually = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = BookManager()

# Can make an illformed Book!!
book = Book.objects.create(title="Some title", should_not_be_set_manually="bad value")
```

**Is there any advantage in doing it like the docs suggest, or is actually overriding `create` just objectively better?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, obviously, you can do that. But if you look closer to the example you are quoting from documentation, it is not about whether you should override create or not, it is about

> If you do so, however, take care not to change the calling signature
>   as any change may prevent the model instance from being saved.

**preserving the calling signature**. Because interfaces available for you may also be used by django internally. If you modify them, things may not break for you but for Django.

In this example, they are not suggesting this for `create` but model constructor.

**Secondly**, even standard interface for `create` is only taking keyword arguments

```
def create(self, **kwargs):
```

But if you modify it to take positional arguments, `def create(self, title):` it will break wherever it is used inside Django or in standard way. So you should **extend** existing functionality not **modify** and most probably **break** it.